# How can I get the ObjectId from inserted item's id in mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
db.get().collection("product").insertOne(product,(err,data)=>{
    console.log(data); 
})
```

result

```
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: new ObjectId("615c620b5fccd83152f4ad2f")
}
```

How do I get the id from the new `ObjectId`?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId.toString/#mongodb-method-ObjectId.toString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out return object is

> acknowledged: true,   insertedId: new
> ObjectId("615c620b5fccd83152f4ad2f")

here **insertedId**  is what you you need.But it is not not returned as a string value.
So to convert it into string by using

```
data.insertedId.toString()
```

this will return _id in string type

Answer (score 0):

You can get the new ObjectId like that:

```
db.get().collection("product").insertOne(product).then(data => data.insertedId);
```

In short just use:

```
data.insertedId
```

Comment: but we will get a new ObjectId("some random number")